# Call function on page load and again on button click, but with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Ajax function that brings data of a web method and displays it on the page. I want to show the first page with 4 item on page load. When the button is clicked, the next four items should show, and so forth for the next clicks. This executes on page load, but when I click the button nothing happens.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var s;
        var countnumber = 0;
        function dos(s, countnumber) {

            participant = s.split("!");
            var i
            for (i = countnumber; i < countnumber + 4; i++) {
                part = participant[i].split("ٌ");

                rk = part[5];

                if (rk == 1) {
                    $("#ts" + i).attr('src', 'con1.png'); 
                } else if (rk == 2) {
                    $("#ts" + i).attr('src', 'con2.png');
                } else if (rk == 3) {
                    $("#ts" + i).attr('src', 'con3.png');
                } else if (rk > 3 && rk < 20) {
                    $("#ts" + i).attr('src', 'briliant.ico');
                } else if (arrlist[5] > 20 && arrlist[5] < 50) {
                    $("#ts").attr('src', 'cup.png');
                } else {
                    $("#ts" + i).attr('src', 'box.png');
                }
                    { $("#st" + i) }
                    $("#use" + i).html(part[1]);
                    $("#rnk" + i).html(part[5]);
                    $("#avg" + i).html(part[2]);
                    $("#pnt" + i).html(part[4]);
                    $("#wit" + i).html(part[3]);
                    $("#kl" + i).html(part[0]);
                    $("#use" + i).html(username);
                }

        }
        $('#kil').bind('click', function () {
            countnumber = countnumber + 4;
            dos(s , countnumber);
        })

        var arrlist;
        var participant, part;
        var username, klll, wt, pt, av, rk;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "rank.aspx/bringdata",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (ret) {
                s = ret.d;
                dos(s, 0);
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: But your code looks correct. What errors do you get? Do you use some debugging tool (firebug, Chrome console)?

Comment: no i have not.it execute for first time and in page load but it dose not work with onclick event

Comment: as freakish states the code looks workable, however without seeing the data you're returning via ajax it's diffcult to debug.. for example if your data is only returning 4 items, that would lead to your code not doing anything when you click.

Comment: are you using this script in ASP.NET??

Comment: no i test it with page load and function bring all the data and i can show each of items in page load but onclick dose not worke

Comment: yes i use aspdotnet but any problem exist in code behiend .im sure

Comment: What happens if you put an alert("hello"); into your button click function? does it alert "hello"?

Comment: yes i put alert(countnumber) and it show number properly

Comment: Ok, well another thing to check is if the elements #ts4, #ts5, #ts6, #ts7 actually exist - i'm guessing they do? Also where does arrlist come from - because it looks to me like it is undefined? Also `$("#ts").attr('src', 'cup.png');` is missing a +i.. is that on purpose?

Comment: @quantum62 :  Can you please check whether you are getting the value of 's' as expected in the button click.

Comment: @pebbl: In fact, the data returned from the Ajax request does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824320/call-function-on-page-load-and-again-on-button-click-but-with-different-paramet/11833897#comment15719358_11824320), you are trying to execute  the `dos()` function via an `onclick=""` event.

The reason it doesn't work is very simple: `dos()` does not exist from the perspective of the global scope.

What you have to do instead is one of the following two:

1. Move the `dos()` function into a globally accessible scope.
2. Attach the `dos()` function to the `click` event via jQuery.

Personally, I would prefer the second option, because it avoids polluting the global namespace.

### From local variables

**Example:** local variables

```
function f() {
    var x = 1;
}

process_x(x); # this will trigger a "ReferenceError: x is not defined"
```

I am sure you are aware, that it is not possible to access a variable that is local to a function from the outside.

### to local functions –

When you define a function inside a function, you are essentially creating a local variable that just happens to be a function.

**Example: function declaration**, this is the form that you have:

```
$(document).ready(function() { # enclosing_function
    function dos() {

    }
});
```

As previously explained, this will lead to `dos()` being local to the `enclosing_function`.

### ... which are essentially the same thing

You can think of it like this to better illustrate the similarity:

**Example:** function expression

```
$(document).ready(function() { # enclosing_function
    var dos = function () {

    };
});
```

### Hoist the colo– functions high

In the example, the two versions are equivalent. However, a function *declaration* – that is, the thing that does not have a an assignment (those are so called "function *expressions*") – are "hoisted" at the top of the code, in which they are defined.

This means, that the definition is moved (or "hoisted") to the very top (or beginning) of the scope in which it was defined. It is not possible to execute code (in that scope) before defining that function.  Thus, you cannot receive a `ReferenceError` for function declarations. (Unless you are in the wrong scope, that is.)

Function *expressions* on the other hand are evaluated the same way all other statements are: as soon as they are encountered by the program flow.

**Example: Hoisting**

```
$(document).ready(function() { # enclosing_function
    # <- This is where "hoisted" is being defined <--
    non_hoisted(); # ReferenceError                 |
    hoisted();     # Works fine                     |
    var non_hoisted = function () { # This is where "non_hoisted" is defined
                                                    |
    };                                              ^
                                                hoisting
    non_hoisted(); # Works fine                     ^
                                                    |
    function hoisted() { ------>-------->------->----

    }
});
```

### One more thing

```
var s;
function dos(s, countnumber) {
    ...
}
```

The formal parameter `s` will introduce `s` as a local variable inside the `dos()` function. It will shadow the `s` variable from its parent scope.

Why do you pass `s` as a parameter to the `dos()` function? You already assign it to the local variable `var s` inside the `enclosing_function()` when the Ajax request returns successfully.

Comment: A well worded & thorough answer, & you are mostly correct with what you state. Except for the fact that dos() will not 'stop existing after the ajax call'. When a function is created in 'local scope' it's definition is remembered by the current scope & all those scopes/functions defined within (i.e. other local functions within the current scope). Because quantum62's bound anonymous click handler is within the same scope as dos() it will retain access to dos (unless the values of dos is overwritten at any point). It is precisely this behaviour that gives JavaScript the power of "Closures".

Comment: As an example of what I mean, check the source here: http://pebbl.co.uk/example/a/

Comment: @pebbl Ah yes, you're right of course. I seem to have missed that click handler. You wouldn't have needed to go through the trouble of creating an example, though ;)

Comment: ah easily done.. oh and no worries, I have a tendency to worry about my clarity when writing... I don't think I can actually write an email without some form of example in it ;)

Comment: @pebbl btw, if you like the answer, you can also show so by upvoting it. Or if you have any pointers on how to improve the answer, let me know.

Comment: ofcourse I'll happily up-vote your post once your answer solves the issue. Whilst the latter part of what you write is good and correct, the actual answer you give isn't the solution that the OP is looking for because `dos` isn't out of scope. Tbh without more information from the OP there isn't much more that can be worked out on their issue unfortunately.

Comment: @pebbl Ah I see. Well, he writes in the comment `"but onclick dose not worke`", I assumed that to be an HTML `onclick=""`, there, `dos()` *is* out of scope.